# Unable to solve the "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 (1)" error is Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a code to implement a time which is fairly simple. But for some reason I'm getting a Thread breakpoint and a blue (lldb) in the debug console, which doesn't tell me what the problem is. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var eggTimes = ["Soft":3, "Medium":5, "Hard":7]
    var totalTime = 0
    var progress: Float = 0.0;
    var passedTime = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
        //timer.invalidate()
    
        totalTime = eggTimes[sender.currentTitle!]!
    
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self,selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   

    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if totalTime > 0
        {
            print(totalTime)
            totalTime-=1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have set a breakpoint.  Look for the blue flag in the margin and click it to deactivate it.  An unrelated tip; `Timer` isn't very accurate.  It ticks after *at least* the interval has elapsed, but possibly longer.  A better approach for timing is to create a `Date` when you start the timer and calculate the elapsed time from that.  You can also create a `Date` that represents the end time and determine if you have reached it yet.  Then you can run the timer faster than once per second and this will give smoother UI updates once you actually put something on screen

Comment: Also, go read up on the breakpoints and the Xcode debugger.  It is a fantastic and very powerful tool that can help you figure out what your code is doing

Comment: Set breakpoint and check button's *currentTitle*. No any issue in this code. Code is perfect and working. Use exception breakpoint and check where is the issue.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! This is very helpful. I'll check out the Date thing